# ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"

Tags: vhdl

I have an error in my vhdl code. I'm using ISE design.
What should I do to solve my problem?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

library std;
use std.standard.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity neuron2 is
    port ( A : in integer :=1;
                B : in integer :=2;

                D : out real);
    constant C : real := 1.25;
    constant E : real := 2.25;
    end neuron2;

architecture Behavioral of neuron2 is

begin

  D <= A+B+C+E;

end Behavioral;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 -
>   "C:\Users\Ida\Downloads\Mojo-Base-VHDL\percobaan2\neuron2.vhd" Line
>   51: found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact
>   overloaded matching definition for "+"  ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 -
>   "C:\Users\Ida\Downloads\Mojo-Base-VHDL\percobaan2\neuron2.vhd" Line
>   46: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are integers while C and E are reals. A and B must be type converted to reals before addition:

```
D <= real(A + B) + C + E;
```

Note: Real types are not synthesisable, so I assume this is simulation only code.

Comment: what shoul i do, when i want to implementation this code in FPGA but real types are not syntesisable?

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to run before you can walk. You describe yourself as a "newbie" but are trying to do something quite difficult - implementing logic doing non-integer maths. Most people who implement non-integer maths in hardware use _fixed-point arithmetic_. That is not easy, but implementing _floating point arithmetic_ is much harder.

Comment: All vendors provide IP cores that can do floating point arithmatic.